# docker commit with marklogic image is not working as expected

Tags: docker, marklogic

I downloaded the MarkLogic docker image from docker hub

I started the container and configured with my app servers, database and forests. deployed code and tried stopping the container and starting and its working as expected.

Then I did commit using:

```
docker commit <<containerid>> <<newname>>:<<tag>>
```

When I try to run the new image using:

```
docker run -d -it -p 8000-8003:8000-8003 -p 7000-7007:7000-7007 <<newname>>:<<tag>>
```

I can see MarkLogic is starting with admin/admin as the user but it does not contain any of my app servers, forests or database.

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. Why am I loosing all my configured MarkLogic?

Comment: `docker commit` is almost never a best practice.  (Say a new version of the base image is released; how will you produce a new version of your updated image?)  Some images are also set up so that you can't create a derived image with preloaded data; this is common for the standard Docker Hub database images, for example.  Can you provide some relevant application source code?

Comment: Agreed that upgrading version will be a challenge. But how we can have the docker image configured with app servers so that we can share the image with others ? Should we always go with docker file to do all the steps? The docker MarkLogic blog says create app servers, configure and commit the container to new image and use it which is what am trying

Comment: Yes, you should _always_ use a Dockerfile to create your images.  (Doubly true since you're asking on a site dedicated to programming questions.)